# Ajuda com migração de classe MySQLi procedural para orientada a objeto

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá, boa tarde.

Comecei a migrar uma classe MySQLi de procedural para Orientada a Objetos e duas funções dessa classe me deixaram em dúvida.

Durante a migração das funções **fetchRow** e **fetch_array** me bateu uma forte dúvida, uma vez que na classe procedural ela é bem esquisita e não achei uma forma de fazê-la parecida na versão orientada a objetos.

```
function &fetchRow($sql, $type = 'DBARRAY_ASSOC') {
    $this->sql = & $sql;
    $queryresult = $this->execute_query(true, $this->connection_master);
    $returnarray = $this->fetch_array($queryresult, $type);
    $this->free_result($queryresult);
    return $returnarray;
}

function fetch_array($queryresult, $type = 'DBARRAY_ASSOC') {
    $result = @$this->functions['fetch_array']($queryresult, $this->fetchtypes["$type"]);
    return $result;
}
```

Deixarei aqui também o código da função **execute_query** que aparece no código:

```
function &execute_query($buffered = true, &$link) {
    $this->connection_recent = & $link;

    if ($queryresult = $this->functions[$buffered ? 'query' : 'query_unbuffered']($link, $this->sql)) {
        // unset $sql to lower memory .. this isn't an error, so it's not needed
        $this->sql = '';

        return $queryresult;
    } else {
        // unset $sql to lower memory .. error will have already been thrown
        $this->sql = '';
    }
}
```

E aqui os meus códigos em OOP que não estão funcionando corretamente...

```
public function fetchRow($query, $type = MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
    $this->Process = self::query($query);
    return $this->Process->fetch_array($type);
}

public function fetch_array($query, $type = MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
    $this->Process = $this->_Engine->query($query);
    return $this->Process->fetch_array($type);
}
```

Os códigos ficaram iguais porque não tive ideia de como foi feita na versão procedural.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54290/discussion-on-question-by-neto-melo-ajuda-com-migracao-de-classe-mysqli-procedur)